# removing edge from undirected edge graph-tool doesn't work when I swap vertices

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

I'm new to graph-tool python library and I'm just trying the basics.
I have a problem with remove_edge command.
let's get to the code:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt
g=gt.Graph(directed=False)
v1=g.add_vertex()
v2=g.add_vertex()
g.add_edge(v1,v2)

g.remove_edge(g.edge(v1,v2))
```

now it works fine but if I change the last line to:

```
g.remove_edge(g.edge(v2,v1))
```

the edge doesn't get removed.
shouldn't they be recognized as the same edge since my graph is undirected?
if not, how can I find a better way to make sure I have deleted the edge between two vertices in a non-multigraph undirected graph?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but reviewing the documentation it seems like the graph is a multigraph. https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.Graph

Comment: thanks, I tried but I wasn't able to find what I am looking for.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The edge gets deleted in both cases. Are you using the newest version 2.23?

Comment: Hi @TiagoPeixoto, Yes this is my version: '2.23 (commit b669e1b7, Sun Sep 24 00:01:08 2017 +0200)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug! It has been fixed now in version 2.24.

Comment: thank you! it feels good to point out a real bug. is the new version available via apt-get?

Comment: But I currently only have access to the versions 2.23-1 and 2.18-1.

Comment: This is not really the place to troubleshoot this... I don't even know if you have Debian or Ubuntu, or which release. But the new packages should be there.